# How to print below Star pattern

Tags: c#

I can't get this answer:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Multidimensional arrays, nested (`do..while`, `while`, `for`)

```cs
char[,] stars = new char[5, 3];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
    {
        stars[i,x]=char.Parse("*");

        Console.Write(stars[i, x]);
```

I want to get 5 "*" stars then 4 in a new Line then 3 in a new Line then 1 in a new Line

Comment: Please added error our troubleshoot. What result you want to required.

Comment: Do you really need multi-dimensional array here?

Comment: how to do with single array?

Comment: Hint : Write proper logic for first and second for loop, use inner for loop to print `*` and outer for loop for new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to understand pattern behind `*`.

star pattern in your program is,

```
0st Line : 5 starts                     //Considering starting index is 0
1st Line : 4 starts                    // starts = n starts - Line no. where n = 5
2nd Line : 3 starts
3rd Line : 2 starts
4th Line : 1 starts
```

i.e.

> Number of stars in single line = n starts - Line number       // 
>   where n = 5

So your code will look like,

```
int n = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++)    
    {                 //^^^^^ n - i is key behind this * pattern
        Console.Write("*");     
    }
    Console.WriteLine();  
}
```

Comment: Tiny bug: Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine); will actually write two new-lines. Only one should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

As this is not about array indexing or address calculation but actual countable objects (stars), I feel that 1-based indexes make more sense here.

Also, the number of stars should be decreasing, so counting backwards makes more sense as well:

```
for (int numStars = 5; numStars >= 1; --numStars)
{
    for (int star = 1; star <= numStars; ++star)
        Console.Write("*");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```